# Is it possible to assign different enums to same value in Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, enums

I want to write class for Enums in Python.

My issue is that I want to have same value for different enum inputs. For example:

```
class Animal(Enum):
    Cat = ['Perian cat', 'Bengal cat', 'Siamese cat']
```

So then I could use it like this:

```
some_animal = Animal('Persian cat')
print(some_animal)
>> Animal.Cat
```

I think it is not possible, but just to be sure I wanted to ask for that here.

**UPDATE**

I tried this solution:

```
class _Cat(Enum):
 BENGAL = 'Bengal cat'
 PERSIAN = 'Persian cat'
 SIAMESE = 'Siamese cat'

class Animal(Enum):
 Cat = _Cat
```

It works in that sense that I can access the values of the Cat class, but what I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
some_animal = Animal('Persian cat')
print(some_animal)
>> Animal.Cat.PERSIAN
```

Thanks.

Comment: What you would want is probably a class that stores the given name and associated enum value (both as fields). Not just enum. Enum is basically a bunch of singletons - even if you were to assign some attribute - e.g. `Animal.Cat.something = 'test'`, then `Animal('Bengal cat').something` will also be set. Because all Animal.Cat is the same object (`is`, not only `==`)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you write short example, please? I think I don't get it all the way.

Comment: What I meant: make a class that holds 2 things: your full description and your enum

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain a close result with the functional API. In fact the hard part in not to have multiple members with same value, but to have names which contain spaces (ie: cannot be identifiers):

```
Animal = Enum('Animal', (('Persian cat', 'cat'), ('Bengal cat', 'cat'),
                         ('Siamese cat', 'cat')))
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> print(Animal['Persian cat'].value)
cat
```

And you can control the equality of the members:

```
>>>Animal['Persian cat'] == Animal['Bengal cat']
True
```

---

But then your enum class becomes very close to a plain `dict`. If additionaly you intend to be able to add new members, then IMHO, it is a hint that what you want is not an `Enum` but a simple `dict`.

Comment: Thank for your reply.

What about case in which I don't have spaces i.e. `persian_cat, bengal_cat` etc.

Is it possible to write a class so I could edit class methods on the way as well? I think it is not possible with functional API.

Simple scenario: I have class the way I described it but additionally if I put there an Enum which is not described in the class I can do something with it.

Comment: @JustPawel: are you sure that a `dict` would not better meet your needs? (just see my edit...)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be to use the `MultiEnum` from `aenum`:

```
from aenum import MultiValueEnum

class Animal(MultiValueEnum):
    CAT = 'Cat', 'Persian cat', 'Bengal cat', 'Siamese cat'
    DOG = 'Dog', 'Greyhound', 'Boxer', 'Great Dane'
    def __repr__(self):
        # make the repr not reduntant
        return "<%s.%s>" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name)
```

and in use:

```
>>> Animal('Bengal cat')
<Animal.CAT>

>>>> Animal('Boxer')
<Animal.DOG>
```

If you need to stick with the stdlib version of `Enum`:

```
from enum import Enum

class Animal(Enum):
    #
    def __new__(cls, *values):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = values[0]
        member.all_values = values
        return member
    #
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        for member in cls:
            if value in member.all_values:
                return member
    #
    CAT = 'Cat', 'Persian cat', 'Bengal cat', 'Siamese cat'
    DOG = 'Dog', 'Greyhound', 'Boxer', 'Great Dane'
    def __repr__(self):
        # make the repr not reduntant
        return "<%s.%s>" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name)
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.